# Best Way to Store Searchable References to Rows in Other Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I would really appreciate advice on database design for MySQL.  I'm making a 2 table database where the COLLECTIONS table has the names of books in a particular series.  Each book has a "recommended reading" list referring to books that aren't in the COLLECTIONS table.  The 2nd table, READING, has a row for each book in a "recommended reading" list.

I want to have a column in the COLLECTIONS table where I can have a list (array?) of the row ids from the READING table.  I want to have a column in the READING table where I have a list (array?) holding the ids of each row in the COLLECTIONS table where that book is mentioned.

My idea is when a query grabs a row from COLLECTIONS it can quickly search the stored list and grab each row from READING that is there.  Also, when a query grabs a row from READING it can quickly search the stored list of id numbers and grab each row from COLLECTIONS.

So each table would have a column for storing id numbers from the other table.  Should these columns be TEXT and have:

```
3, 16, 56
```

Or is there a better way to store this?  I appreciate suggestions on this.

Comment: You're not making a two table database!

Answer (score 2):

Dont use array create a relational table and keep 3NF

```
   Collections (collection_id, ... )
   Reading (reading_id, .... )
   Collection_Reading (collection_id, reading_id)
```

That way you only need update one table `Collection_Reading` when something change instead of update 2 arrays. Also